# CXF With open session in view pattern

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, cxf

I have a few REST webservices that I'm exposing using the CXF Servlet.  However I've ran into issues with a class that needs to a collection that's lazily loaded (more than one list). I'm getting this:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: my.Model.lists, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

My cxf configuration is fairly simple:

```
    <jaxrs:server address="/v2" id="connectionService">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="testService" />
            <ref bean="modelServicesLogic" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean="myLoggingFilter"/>
            <ref bean="jacksonProvider"/>
            <ref bean="myExceptionHandler" />

        </jaxrs:providers>
    </jaxrs:server>
```

How can I implement the "open session in view" pattern so that my hibernate session is available when Jackson is serializing the object?

Comment: Maybe with a servlet filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Spring see below:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html

or

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.html

Comment: That did it.  I had read somewhere that it didn't work with CXF, so I hadn't tried that at first, but it was as easy as that.